# How to split a string by commas in PHP

Tags: php, string

I am a beginner with PHP and I would like to know how can I get the parts `x`, `y`, `z`, and `t` of a sequence of characters which has the form `"x, y, z, t"`:

Example:

```
$str1 = "2,161,0,0"; 
$str2 = "2,3,10,4";
```

for `$str1` we have to recover:

```
2 -> x

161 -> y

0 -> z

0 -> t
```

Comment: @misorude to be fair, sepehr wrote that title

Comment: @RobbieAverill oh yeah you’re right, with the original title they’d have a hard time finding anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
explode(',', $str1);
```

More on explode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1):

Since you need the string components as separate variables, which is well, weird, you also need to make use of [`list`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) as well:

```
list($x, $y, $z, $t) = explode(',', $str1);
```

Or using the [short list syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/short_list_syntax) since PHP 7.1:

```
[$x, $y, $z, $t] = explode(',', $str1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this example:

```
$str1 = "2,161,0,0"; 

$array = explode(',', $str1);
print_r($array);
```

Output will then be:

```
array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 161
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
)
```

Read more about `explode()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).